# IProgressMonitor example needed for uncertain long process database transaction

Tags: multithreading, eclipse-rcp

I am new to RCP and I am building one product where i have "Import" feature which imports the approx 50000 data from excel. I want to show the progress in progress bar. I have tried many examples but couldn't extract required code may be i don't know how to write proper way. Please provide me example with few steps which can help to understand the flow. It would be good if steps say where to write IProgressMonitor and database connectivity code which will import data from excel and insert into database.

I need also some more stuff like calling each method string should be changed to different strings as i have mentioned in Image. By doing that user can aware that what is happening behind the scene.

### Below is the sample code I have tried

new ProgressMonitorDialog(shell).run(true, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {
     @Override
     public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException,
                InterruptedException {
                    try {
                        monitor.beginTask("Importing Data...", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);

```
                    if (monitor.isCanceled())
                        return;
                    try {
                        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {@
                            Override
                            public void run() {
                                Snippet s = new Snippet();
                                // What should i write here ?
                            }
                        });
                        monitor.subTask(String.valueOf(i)); // How to show elapse time ?
                        Thread.sleep(100); // When to sleep thread without knowing how much time it will take ? 
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } finally {
                    monitor.done();
                }
            });
```

Thank in advance.

[image: Please click Here to see How I expect Progress Bar]

Comment: Have you  read the [Using Progress Monitors](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Progress-Monitors/article.html) article?

Comment: Yes. I read it but to be frank i didn't get it

Comment: What exactly didn't you get and what have you tried so far?

Comment: If you want anyone to read your code, you should probably improve its readability. Why don't you edit your question and add the code?

Comment: The code is still only half readable. Loading from a database or other long running tasks are usually done in a background thread to keep the UI responsive. RCP has so-called Jobs to help with thread management, progress reporting, and related things. I recommend reading about the [Eclipse Jobs API](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html)

Comment: Could you please shared one example which could fit to my expectation ? I will handle database operations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic Job that uses a progress monitor with an unknown total work and informs about the sub task that is about to be executed

```java
Job job = new Job( "Import Data" ) {
  @Override
  protected IStatus run( IProgressMonitor monitor ) {
    monitor.beginTask( "Importing Data...", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN );
    try {
      monitor.subTask( "Opening Database..." );
      // connect to db
      monitor.subTask( "Reading Elements..." );
      // read elements
      ...
    } finally {
      monitor.done();
    }
    return Status.OK_STATUS;
  }
};
job.schedule();
```

For refinements and more details you should really read the respective articles and documentation.

Comment: I have different methods for importing like ImportElements(),ImportCustomisation(),ImportX(),ImportY(). How to execute method step by step along with updating monitor.subTask() ?

Comment: Just call your methods after setting the sub task name.

Comment: By doing it last subTask is called.

Comment: Ha? (In English: I am afraid I don't understand what you mean.)

Comment: Do i need to sleep the thread in between two subTask because without writing sleep , progress bar doesn't show ?